# Arduino Communicate with android through bluetooth

Tags: arduino, android-bluetooth

Currently i success to build the communication between the android device and arduino through bluetooth. As arduino will send string "ON" or "OFF" depend on the LED condition to Android through bluetooth and my android able to receive the string "LED:ARE:OFF" and "LED:ARE:ON" through the read() function. But currently i want to read a data by split the string into 3 from the LED, for example: "LED:ARE:OFF" into "LED" , "Are", "OFF" , but i failed to received the data. I had tried the String.split(":") to split out the aaa:bbb:ccc into 3 part, and it unable to read the data as well.  Please help

```
Arduino Code:

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>// import the serial library

SoftwareSerial Genotronex(10, 11); // RX, TX
int ledpin=8; // led on D13 will show blink on / off
long previousMillis = 0;        // will store last time LED was updated

long interval = 1000;           // interval at which to blink (milliseconds)
int ledState = LOW;             // ledState used to set the LED
long Counter=0; // counter will increase every 1 second
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Genotronex.begin(9600);
  Genotronex.println("Bluetooth On please wait....");
  pinMode(ledpin,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if(currentMillis - previousMillis > interval) {
    // save the last time you blinked the LED
    previousMillis = currentMillis;  
     Counter+=1;


    delay(4000);
    // if the LED is off turn it on and vice-versa:
    if (ledState == LOW){
      ledState = HIGH;
      Genotronex.print("LED:ARE:ON");
          digitalWrite(ledpin, ledState);

      }
    else{
      ledState = LOW;
      Genotronex.print("LED:ARE:OFF");
          digitalWrite(ledpin, ledState);

    }
    // set the LED with the ledState of the variable:

  }

}
```

---

```
Android Code:

btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);


int delay = 1000;   // delay in ms
int period = 100;   // repeat in ms

timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
{
    public void run()
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            final byte data = read();

            readMessageHandler.post(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {

                    if (data != 1){

                        message = txtReceived.getText().toString() + (char)data;}

                    else{
                        message = "";
                        }
                    String message;
                    //New Code for split the data
                    String[] parts = message.split(":"); // escape .
                    String part0 = parts[0];
                    String part1 = parts[1];
                    String part2 = parts[2];      
                    txtReceived.setText(part0);
                    //End of Split
                    // txtReceived.setText(Message);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}, delay, period);

private byte read()
{

    byte dataRead = 0;


    try
    {
        dataRead = (byte) inputStream.read();
    }
    catch(IOException readException)
    {
        toastText = "Failed to read from input stream: " + readException.getMessage();
        Toast.makeText(Blood_Pressure.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return dataRead;
}
```